# Invoking appropriate methods for strings

Tags: c#, methods

This has a game development project under itself, but it's really about coding and mapping data to other pieces of data. This is why I decided to post it here.

The format that I'm using for external inventory item data storage:

```
[ID:IT_FO_TROUT]
[Name:Trout]
[Description:A raw trout.]
[Value:10]

[3DModel:null]
[InventoryIcon:trout]

[Tag:Consumable]
[Tag:Food]
[Tag:Stackable]

[OnConsume:RestoreHealth(15)]
[OnConsume:RestoreFatigue(15)]
```

The question is concentrated upon the last 2 **OnConsume** properties. Basically, the two properties mean that when the item gets consumed, the consumer's health goes up by 15 points, and his fatigue does so as well. This, in the background, invokes 2 different methods:

```
void RestoreHealth(Character Subject, int Amount);
void RestoreFatigue(Character Subject, int Amount);
```

How would you go about mapping the methods to their in-file string counterparts? This is what I thought of:

1. Every time an item gets consumed, a list of strings (the events) gets passed to an *Item event manager*. The manager parses each string and calls the appropriate methods. Very easy to set up, and since this is not an operation that happens too often, the impact on performance might not be considerable (strings will also be tiny (max 10-15 characters) in size, and parsed in O(n) time).
2. Each **inventory item** (class) parses the string events once and only once, on initialization. Each string event gets mapped to its appropriate method via a  dictionary. This is the most efficient method in terms of performance that I can think of, but it makes it extremely difficult to do other things:
   All of the values in the dictionary would have to be delegates of the same kind. This means I cannot keep

   *a) RestoreHealth(int)*

   *b) SummonMonster(Position, Count)*

   in the same dictionary, and would have to set a new data structure for each kind of callable method. This is a tremendous amount of work to do.

Some ways that came to mind, to improve both methods:

1. I could use some sort of temporary cache inside the *Item event
   manager*, so that an item's **OnConsume** events don't get parsed
   twice? I might hit the same issues as the ones I hit during 2)
   though, as the cache would have to be a `map<InventoryItem,List<delegate>>`.
2. The **hashtable** data structure inside the .NET libraries allows
       for any kind of object to be a key and/or value at any given time
       (unlike the dictionary). I could use this and map **string A to
       delegate X**, while also having mapped **string B to delegate Y**
       inside the same structure. Any reasons why I should not do this? Can
       you foresee any trouble that would be brought by this method?

I was also thinking about something in the ways of reflection, but I'm not exactly experienced when it comes to it. And I'm pretty sure parsing the string every time is faster.

**EDIT**

My final solution, with Alexey Raga's answer in mind. Using interfaces for each kind of event.

```
public interface IConsumeEvent    
{    
    void ApplyConsumeEffects(BaseCharacter Consumer);   
}
```

Sample implementer (particular event):

```
public class RestoreHealthEvent : IConsumeEvent
{    
    private int Amount = Amount;

    public RestoreHealthEvent(int Amount)
    {
        this.Amount = Amount;
    }

    public void ApplyConsumeEffects(BaseCharacter Consumer)   
    {
        Consumer.Stats.AlterStat(CharacterStats.CharStat.Health, Amount);    
    }    
}
```

Inside the parser (the only place where we care about the event's particularities - because we're parsing the data files themselves):

```
RestoreHealthEvent ResHealthEv = new RestoreHealthEvent (Value);
NewItem.ConsumeEvents.Add (ResHealthEv );
```

When a character consumes an item:

```
foreach (IConsumeEvent ConsumeEvent in Item.ConsumeEvents)
{
    //We're inside a parent method that's inside a parent BaseCharacter class; we're consuming an item right now.
    ConsumeEvent.ApplyConsumeEffects(this);
}
```

Comment: Create objects that are constructed/initialised from your config file....Object.Consume(this) should have the ability to call this.AddHealth(int)

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not "map" them to "command" classes once-and-only-once instead?

For example,

```
[OnConsume:RestoreHealth(15)]
[OnConsume:RestoreFatigue(15)]
```

could be mapped to `RestoreHealth` and `RestoreFatigue` command classes that can be defined as:

```
public sealed class RestoreHealth : ICommand {
    public int Value { get; set; }
    //whatever else you need
}

public sealed class SummonMonster : ICommand {
    public int Count {get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

Consider commands as just wrappers for your parameters at this point ;) So instead of passing multiple parameters you always wrap them and pass only one.
It also gives a bit of semantics too.

Now you can map your inventory items to *commands* that need to be "sent" when each item is consumed.

You can implement a simple "bus" interface like:

```
public interface IBus {
    void Send(ICommand command);
    void Subscribe(object subscriber);
}
```

and now you just get an instance of `IBus` and call its `Send` method when appropriate.

By doing this you separate your "definition" (*what* needs to be done) and your logic (*how* to perform an action) concerns.

For the *receiving* and *reacting* part you implement the `Subscribe` method to interrogate the `subscriber` instance (again, once and only once) figuring out all its method which can "handle" commands.
You can come up with some `IHandle<T> where T: ICommand` interface in your handlers, or just find them by convention (any `Handle` method that accepts only one argument of `ICommand` and returns `void`), or whatever works for you.

It is basically the same part of "delegate/action" lists that you were talking about except that now it is *per command*:

```
map<CommandType, List<action>>
```

Because all the actions now accept only *one* parameter (which is `ICommand`) you can easily keep them all in the same list.

When some command is received, your `IBus` implementation just gets the list of actions for the given command type and simply calls these actions passing the given command as a parameter.

Hope it helps.

**Advanced**: you can do one step further: have a `ConsumeItem` command:

```
public sealed void ConsumeItem: ICommand {
    public InventoryItem Item { get; set; }
}
```

You already have a class that is responsible for holding a map between InventoryItem and Commands, so this class can become a *process manager*:

1. It subscribes to `ConsumeItem` command (through the bus)
2. In its `Handle` method it gets the list of commands for the given inventory item
3. It sends these commands to the bus.

Well, now we have separated clearly these three concerns:

1. While consuming an inventory item we just "know" about `IBus` and send a `ConsumeItem` command and we don't care what happens next.
2. The "ConsumeInventoryManager" (whatever you call it) also knows about `IBus', subscribes for`ConsumeItem` command and "knows" *what needs to be done* when each item is consumed (list of commands). It just sends these commands and doesn't care who and how handle them.
3. The business logic (characters, monsters, etc) just handle the commands that make sense to them (`RestoreHealth`, `Die`, etc) and don't care where (and why) they came from.

Good luck :)

Comment: This looks like a pretty valid alternative :) Thanks a lot! I'll start a bounty tomorrow and see others' alternatives and/or opinions.

Comment: In the end, I went with something that I came up with after analyzing your solution. It's really, much much cleaner and safer than just using reflection! I'll edit my first post to describe this. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use reflection, that is define a method that invokes the desired method based on the specified name. Here's a working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass someInstance = new SomeClass();
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        someInstance.Call("SayHello", name);
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    public void SayHello(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hello, {0}!", name));
    }

    public void Call(string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

You can do it this way provided the following conditions hold:

1. You are absolutely sure that a call is possible, that is a method of the specified name exists and the number and types of parameters are correct
2. The method of the specified name is not overloaded, otherwise You'll get a `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException`
3. There exists a superclass from which all of the classes You want to use the `Call` method on derive; You should define this method in that class

To assure* that conditions 1. and 2. are satisfied You could use a more specific version of `Type.GetMethod` which takes into account not only the name of the method, but also the number and types of the parameters, and check that there is such a method before invoking it; then the `Call` method would look like this (**it won't work for methods with parameters marked as* `out` *or* `ref`):

```
public void Call(string methodName, params object[] args)
{
    //get the method with the specified name and parameter list
    Type[] argTypes = args.Select(arg => arg.GetType()).ToArray();
    MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, argTypes);

    //check if the method exists and invoke it
    if (method != null)
        method.Invoke(this, args);
}
```

**REMARK**: `MethodInfo.Invoke` *method actually returns an* `object`, *so You could define the* `Call` *method to return some value by specifying the return type and using the* `return` *keyword together with an appropriate cast or some other method of converting the result to the desired type, if it's possible - remember to check if it is.*

If condition 3. isn't satisfied, I'd go with writing an extension method. Here's an example of an extension method that returns a generic value, which **I think** should be sufficient in most cases (*again, it won't work with* `ref` *or* `out`) and should work on almost every object possible in the .NET Framework (I'd be grateful for pointing out a counterexample):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    //invoke a method with the specified name and parameter list
    // and return a result of type T
    public static T Call<T>(this object subject, string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        //get the method with the specified name and parameter list
        Type[] argTypes = args.Select(arg => arg.GetType()).ToArray();
        MethodInfo method = subject.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, argTypes);

        //check if the method exists
        if (method == null)
            return default(T); //or throw an exception

        //invoke the method and get the result
        object result = method.Invoke(subject, args);

        //check if something was returned
        if (result == null)
            return default(T); //or throw an exception
        //check if the result is of the expected type (or derives from it)
        if (result.GetType().Equals(typeof(T)) || result.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))
            return (T)result;
        else
            return default(T); //or throw an exception
    }

    //invoke a void method more conveniently
    public static void Call(this object subject, string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        //invoke Call<object> method and ignore the result
        subject.Call<object>(methodName, args);
    }
}
```

You should then be able to use, for example, `someObject.Call<string>("ToString")` instead of `someObject.ToString()`. Finally, at this point I'd strongly recommend:

1. Use more specific type than `object` if possible
2. Use some more sophisticated and unique name than `Call` - it may get obscured in case some class has a method with the same signature defined
3. Lookup *covariance* and *contravariance* to get more useful knowledge

Comment: How would you estimate the performance hit will feel like in comparison to Alexey's solution?

Comment: It's really hard to tell, but to speed things up You could create a dictionary of MethodInfo objects at initialization, which actually deals with Your concerns 2a) and 2b).